# Lumen Carbon changing phpMyAdmin timestamp

Tags: php, phpmyadmin, timestamp, lumen

I'm having a problem in using Lumen Carbon for my phpmyadmin created_at timestamp. 
Carbon is changing the time that is in my database that even setting default timezone for both php.ini, app.php on laravel/lumen-framework/config/ doen't work

Date from phpmyadmin database:

```
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
column        date & time            type
- - - - -  - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
created_at    2019-03-22 09:41:47    timestamp
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
```

Date resulted using Carbon of Lumen:

```
Carbon @1553190107 {#87 ▼
  date: 2019-03-22 01:41:47.0 Asia/Manila (+08:00)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For some reason, I guessed that `timestamp` of mysql does not compliment Carbon... So I changed my created_at column's type from `timestamp` to `datetime`... Solved my problem...